# Mesh is displayed differently in Unity with some undesireable visual elements

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes

I'm not sure what to make of this:

[image]

this is what it looks like in unity scene view/game view

This is, for example, the same upright triangle in microsoft's 3d object viewer:

[image]

I have no clue what to make of the undesirable, shadowed lines in unity.

How do I get rid of them?

Edit: Tried looking at face normals in blender, they seem fine to me

[image]

setting `Normals` to `None` on the mesh results in this:

[image]

Setting it to `Calculate` or `Import` doesn't seem to make a difference, and disabling/enabling mesh optimization or mesh compression doesn't seem to make a difference. Nor does disabling `Generate Lightmap UVs`

Comment: Could be an artifact of a weird topology combined with weird UVs. How does the mesh look in the wireframe view of your preferred 3d modeling program? It might also be relevant to know what render pipeline you are using and how the material is configured.

Comment: It looks like vertices with coincident positions but different normals (creating a hard creased edge where the triangle meets the square) have been merged. That means the normals from the inclined side of the triangle are getting blended into what should be flat polygons on the square, and vice versa, leading to the weird shading you see. Are you using a normal map with this model in either tool, or have you enabled any mesh compression settings to try to reduce the vertex count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing quite a bit with the import settings, I decided to try setting `Smoothness source` to `None`.

Lo and behold!

[image]

Setting it to `From Smoothing Groups` (as opposed to `Prefer Smoothing Groups`) produces the same results.

I have no clue what to make of it.